# Autogenerate C# WebApi from Models

Tags: c#, rest

Does anyone know of any tools that can generate a C# WebApi REST Interface for a model?

What I would like is to define my model and add attributes that describe properties of the resource in the context of standard REST architecture. After defining the model and adding attributes, the hypothetical tool would generate all the code needed for implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if this tool will work for your very specific case, but it is a code generator nonetheless and appears to be relatively versatile.

http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/generator

I'm assuming you already searched for a code generator to suit your need so if this one doesn't work for you, you may have to face the music and write one yourself.

A co-worker I work with here wrote a generator in C# that pulled schema/data structure info from a SQL database, took that info, and simply output C# code to a .cs file.

I know this isn't the best answer, but hopefully it helps in at least some way.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Use OData to create simple rest services(GET, POST, PUT, DELETE). OData is being widely accepted by many UI components which allow us to use dynamic querying at request level.

You can simply replace the Model Names and DTO Names in an odata controller to use it to other model's controller.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can - in Visual Studio it can be in a couple of minutes. Open Web App with API structure with different variants- it has all the methods in place of HTTP verbs like Get, Put, Post, delete etc
In this you can then add a simple library where use ADO.NET edmx file by adding a connection of SQL and within no time your layer of data acces is created
Now you can leverage this in your Web API
This way you can implement the REST based architecture

You can also make it by adding WebGet attribute in WCF created strcture but above is simple approach if trying on a new solution!
Hope this helps